# Risk to academic reputation by publicly requesting pay-walled articles

Tags: publications, legal-issues, reputation

The Twitter hashtag [#ICanHazPDF](https://twitter.com/hashtag/icanhazpdf) has been popular among academics as a method for peer-to-peer exchange of pay-walled articles. Some people call this practice "piracy", and it could be illegal depending on the publisher policies.

Apparently, many users use it with real names and real profile pictures.

What are real risks to academic reputation and career of people by publicly requesting pay-walled articles?

I'm looking for an objective assessment.

Comment: It will be news to me the first time someone points to a case of a hashtag, or anything on Twitter, having an impact on academic reputation.

Comment: @LaurentDuval Risk to reputation of individuals and organizations **can** be objectively assessed and managed. #UseGoogleBeforePostingNiceComments

Comment: @DanielR.Collins I edited the question to make it clearer that it's about requesting PDFs on Twitter, which is a "dubious" practice, rather than merely using the hashtag.

Comment: _Risk to reputation of individuals and organizations can be objectively assessed and managed_ — [citation needed]

Comment: @JeffE Here we go:

http://dx.doi.org/10.1108/09513570810863932

http://dx.doi.org/10.1258/cr.2009.090045

http://dx.doi.org/10.1287/orsc.1050.0127

http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-04008-9_2

https://books.google.com/books?id=rjuBTqZPS_EC

https://books.google.com/books?id=aaeLF_3VPJEC

https://books.google.com/books?id=TWqUAgAAQBAJ

http://www.criticaleye.com/insights-servfile.cfm?id=409

Comment: If the article describes research that was funded by my tax dollars, then it would negatively affect my opinion of the author and the journal if the paper was not freely available on a site such as arxiv.org. In terms of legality, it's not at all obvious to me whether #ICanHazPDF falls within the US fair use exception to copyright.

Comment: @Orion I agree that your citations support _assessed and managed_, but they do not support your claim of objectivity.

Comment: @JeffE **They do**. Reputation _management_ implicitly involves _objective_ assessment! Objective measures of corporate reputation may include client satisfaction.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Here's something on twitter having effect on reputation! https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2013/08/07/fat-shaming-professor-faces-censure-university

Answer (score 1):

Probably very little unless they're very pro-copyright or lawsuits start to happen. In the former case, they'd look hypocritical. In the latter, a University might be less likely to hire the academic to protect themselves from future liability issues.

Comment: "a University might be dissuaded from the academic" This seems like a typo or a mistake in diction. Could you clarify?